# Number of real roots of a degree 10 polynomial with several parameters

Tags: polynomials

Consider the real polynomial $x^2 + (x^2+1)(ax^8 + bx^6 + cx^5 + dx^4 + ex^3 + fx^2 + g)$ where $a < 0$, $g > 0$ and there are no terms of degree $1$ or $7$ in the second bracket. Can this polynomial ever have $10$ real roots?  Numerical evidence suggests that the maximum number of real roots is not attainable. (There are similar questions in other even degree polynomials, where the second bracket has even degree and no terms in $x$ or one less than the degree of the bracket, with leading terms and constant term having the same sign as above.)

Comment: A small observation is that $-1<a<0$. For if $P(x)$ is the polynomial then $P(i)=-1$, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Hence if $r_1,\dots,r_{10}$ are the zeros (all real) then $a\prod_j(i-r_j)=-1$. Taking absolute values squared gives $a^2\prod_k(1+r_j^2)=1$, so $|a|\leq 1$. If $|a|=1$ then all $r_j=0$, contradicting $g>0$. Hence $|a|<1$, so $-1<a<0$.